# pruning a special graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

You are given a very special graph. The vertices of the graph come in three
columns: left, center, and right. The edges connect vertices from the left to
vertices in the center, and from the center to the right; there are no left to
right edges. The graph also has the property that it does not contain any
“closed diamonds”, meaning there are never two routes from a vertex on the
left to a vertex on the right. See [sample graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USVtF.jpg)

You are asked to prune the graph following these rules. For each left
vertex, remove all but one of its outgoing edges. When you remove a
(left,center) edge, then also remove the corresponding center vertex. When
you remove a center vertex, then also remove all of its (center,right) edges
and the corresponding right vertices.

Is it possible in this way to remove all of the right vertices? If so, give
an example. If not, prove it. (I believe it is not possible, and I’m looking
for a proof.)

Comment: arent both of your OK sample graphs counter-examples? What if all the vertices on the left have degree $1$ at the start?  Then you don't remove anything.

Comment: "very special" is over-valued.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question is whether there is any graph that allows removing all its right vertices. There are plenty, for example the complete bipartite graph $K_{2,2}$ on the left and center augmented with two vertices on the right and two parallel edges between the center and the right. Your rules allows removing the two parallel edges in $K_{2,2}$, thus removing all center and right vertices.